# How do I catch thrown errors with async / await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, error-handling, async-await

Here's some code:

```
  import 'babel-polyfill'

  async function helloWorld () {
    throw new Error ('hi')
  }

  helloWorld()
```

I also went deep and tried this as well:

```
  import 'babel-polyfill'

  async function helloWorld () {
    throw new Error ('hi')
  }

  async function main () {
    try {
      await helloWorld()
    } catch (e) {
      throw e
    }
  }

  main()
```

and:

```
import 'babel-polyfill'

 async function helloWorld () {
   throw new Error ('hi')
 }

try {
 helloWorld()
} catch (e) {
 throw e
}
```

This works:

```
import 'babel-polyfill'

async function helloWorld () {
  throw new Error('xxx')
}

helloWorld()
.catch(console.log.bind(console))
```

Comment: I think you should catch in async function itself.

Comment: updated: still doesn't work @zb'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it's kind of tricky, but the reason you're not catching the error is because, at the top level, the entire script can be thought of as a *synchronous* function. Anything you want to catch asynchronously needs to be wrapped in an `async` function or using Promises.

So for instance, this will swallow errors:

```
async function doIt() {
  throw new Error('fail');
}

doIt();
```

Because it's the same as this:

```
function doIt() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(function () {
    throw new Error('fail');
  });
}

doIt();
```

At the top level, you should always add a normal Promise-style catch() to make sure that your errors get handled:

```
async function doIt() {
  throw new Error('fail');
}

doIt().catch(console.error.bind(console));
```

In Node, there is also the global `unhandledRejection` event on [process](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) that you can use to catch all Promise errors.

Answer (score 7):

[`async` is meant to be used with Promises](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/). If you reject the promise, then you can `catch` the error, if you resolve the promise, that becomes the return value of the function.

```
async function helloWorld () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    reject('error')
  });
}


try {
    await helloWorld();
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Error occurred', e);
}
```

Comment: I just found you can throw like normal and just use `.catch` (show above). You're method doesn't work for me.

Comment: @ThomasReggi [This link claims it should work](http://www.sitepoint.com/simplifying-asynchronous-coding-es7-async-functions/) (and also throwing exceptions)  Maybe it's a bug in babel? Yes the `.catch()` will work, but I thought your question was about being able to `try(){}catch(){}` it

Comment: AFAIK, you can only use the await keyword within an aync function.

Comment: @jehan it comes before a function to signify you can call it with await . https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/

Comment: Works for me with axios promises.

Answer (score 1):

To catch an error from an async function, you can await the error:

```
async function helloWorld () {
  //THROW AN ERROR FROM AN ASYNC FUNCTION
  throw new Error('hi')
}

async function main() {
  try {
    await helloWorld()
  } catch(e) {
    //AWAIT THE ERROR WITHIN AN ASYNC FUNCTION
    const error = await e
    console.log(error)
  }
}

main()
```

Alternatively, you can just await the error message:

```
async function main() {
  try {
    await helloWorld()
  } catch(e) {
    //AWAIT JUST THE ERROR MESSAGE
    const message = await e.message
    console.log(message)
  }
}
```