# npm test doesn't catch errors thrown inside async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, async-await, babeljs

I'm currently working on some tests scripts for my project. The code is written in ES7 and compiled using `babel`

---

First some background:

Let's say you run `npm test` and the test file looks like this:

```
function foo (bar) {
  if (!bar) throw new Error('foooo')
  console.log(bar)
}
foo() // No argument given
```

Now when you run this script the npm will show you an error like this:

```
$ npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

This is the desired output, something went wrong, you do not want to release this software yet since there's an error in there.

### So what's my question?

---

Okey so I have a test script setup like this:

```
async function init () {
  const status = await someRequestPromise()
  if (status.error) throw status.error
  console.log(status.result) // Log the result of this async request...
}
init()
```

To run my test first I compile the ES7 using babel like so:

```
$ babel src -d dist
```

and then run `npm test`

---

### The result

[image: CLI screenshot]
To be clear, npm did not trigger the error...

I also tried the following code, however this did not change anything...

```
async function init () {
  const status = await someRequestPromise()
  if (status.error) throw status.error
  console.log(status.result) // Log the result of this async request...
} 

try {
  init()
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

---

I'd like to know how I can trigger npm to catch the error and report the fact that the test failed. Also I'd like to know how to catch the error's, since node marks them as unhandled right now, even with the try catch block.

PS. adding an `await` statement in front of the `init()` function causes a syntax error, please don't suggest that.

Comment: By default, `npm test` doesn't do anything. What testing runner/framework are you using? Many of them support async test, e.g. Mocha does.

Comment: npm catches the fact that the script exits on an unhandled error. Correct?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. @pavlo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I catch an error from async without using await?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30649994/1048572), [How do I catch thrown errors with async / await?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33562284/1048572) and many more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `async/await` returns promises, you must handle rejections (just as the console output suggests) via `.catch`:

```
const handle = init()
handle
  .then((result) => handleSuccess(result))
  .catch(({message}) => console.log(message))
```

`try/catch` (at least, in my experience)is for sync code.

EDIT:

To make the script 'crash', You may just add a `process.exit(1)`.

```
const handle = init()
handle
  .then((result) => handleSuccess(result))
  .catch(({message}) => {
     console.log(message)
     process.exit(1)
   })
```

Comment: I'll look into it. Though `try/catch` blocks where best practice in combo with async/await

Comment: Yes it is, if you're handling errors *within* the async function and not outside -- just like its predecessor, ES6 Generators. Does that make sense? Also, where'd you find that information about `try/catch`?

Comment: Information was based upon my very own memory haha. Read it somewhere someday... (I'll test the `.catch()` approach quickly)

Comment: Okey so yeah, while that is the desired way to handle any errors its still not a valid way to make npm actually catch the fact that the program failed. You're handeling the error and therefore it's expected... the script won't crash.

Comment: simply add `process.exit(1)` in the `catch` section

Answer (score 0):

Years late, but I believe one correct way to do this (without top level await) is to move the try catch into the 'init' function

```
async function init () {
  // Try / catch with async / await is basically syntactic sugar for resolve() / reject() 
  try {
    // This async call MUST use await or the promise will not resolve here, 
    // and thus the try / catch wrapping the async call will not trigger
    const status = await someRequestPromise() 
    
    if (status.error) {
      // Throw to reject the promise returned from init()
      throw status.error
    }

    // Log the success of this async request
    console.log(status.result) 
  // Catch your error to do logging.
  } catch (e) {
    // Log the failure of this async request
    console.log(e) 

    // Rethrow to return the promise as rejected (with result as the error object)
    // If you do not rethrow, the promise from init() will return as resolved
    throw e 
  }
  // Return the promise from init() as fulfilled (with result as void)
} 

// Use a thenable to initiate the promise chain at the top level
init().then();
```

The comments might not be 100% accurate, but it's trying to get the idea across.

Basically a try catch can be used to resolve or reject promises, but only if the promises are awaited somewhere within the try/catch